# Webpack - how to tell not compiling a js file for a specific entry point

Tags: npm, webpack, fonts, node-modules, webfonts

### Context

I am actually managing some dependencies via `npm`. Then I wrote a `webpack.config.js` to handle my imports :

1. Bundle Jquery + popper + Bootstrap.js
2. Bundle codemirror with my modules needs (xml autocomplete and so on)
3. ...
4. Collect fonts from the fontawesome node_module

I am using django, so there is a `collectstatic` command which is helping me to collect all scripts, fonts, styles etc. to the folder I want. Everything is working great :

- My bundled scripts are available
- And for style sheets, I'm using relative imports to the 'vendor' node_module.

I am capable to get fonts to node_modules, and deliver it to the correct folder as expected.

### Problem

I'm new to webpack world, and for sure I'm not using it as it should be, but it's working.
However when I run to compile my stuffs, an **extra file is generated** `fontawesome.js` in my `fonts` folder, is it possible to avoid this **unexpected behavior**.
What am I missing ?

It is not a big deal as long as I'm not importing this file, but I don't want to pollute my repo.

#### Edit

I updated the code of my webpack config.
Well, I figured out that the `js` file was generated from the `filename` in my entry point. But I don't want this file :)

### wepback.config.js

`"webpack": "^5.6.0",`

```
var path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'); // Extract css in its own file
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path_modules = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const base_path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const dist_static = path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpacked_src');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bootstrap: {
            import: [
                base_path + '/bootstrap/bootstrap-bundle.js',
                //base_path + '/bootstrap/test.scss'
            ],
            filename: 'js_packed/[name].js',
        },
        fontawesome: {
            import: [
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot',
                //path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot',
                //path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot',
                //path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff',
                path_modules + '/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2',
            ],
            filename: 'fonts/[name].js'
        },
        codemirror: {
            import: [
                base_path + '/codemirror/code-mirror.js',
                path_modules + '/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css',
                path_modules + '/codemirror/theme/monokai.css', // Import the theme style --> Little selection midnight / material-darker / material-ocean / monokai (sublimetext)
                path_modules + '/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css',
            ],
            filename: 'js_packed/[name].js',
        },
        vue: {
            import: [
                base_path + '/vue/vue.js',
            ],
            filename: 'js_packed/[name].js',
        },
    },
    output: {
        path: dist_static
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
        autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css_packed/[name].css", // change this RELATIVE to the output.path
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // instead of style-loader
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {outputPath: 'css/', name: '[name].min.css'}
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

### fontawesome.js

And the content of the **generated file**, if it can help webpack experts :

```
(() => {
    "use strict";
    var t = {};
    t.g = function () {
        if ("object" == typeof globalThis) return globalThis;
        try {
            return this || new Function("return this")()
        } catch (t) {
            if ("object" == typeof window) return window
        }
    }(), (() => {
        var r;
        t.g.importScripts && (r = t.g.location + "");
        var e = t.g.document;
        if (!r && e && (e.currentScript && (r = e.currentScript.src), !r)) {
            var p = e.getElementsByTagName("script");
            p.length && (r = p[p.length - 1].src)
        }
        if (!r) throw new Error("Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser");
        r = r.replace(/#.*$/, "").replace(/\?.*$/, "").replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "/"), t.p = r + "../"
    })(), t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p, t.p
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11671

In the meantime, it's straight forward to add a custom webpack plugin that will remove these files. Here's what I'm using to delete all JS files (because I'm using a CSS file as my entry):

```js
plugins: [
    {
      // Delete empty JS files; work around for https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11671
      apply: (compiler) => {
        compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('DeleteJSFilesPlugin', (compilation) => {
          const iter = compilation.emittedAssets.entries();
          for (const [key] of iter) {
            if (key.match(/.*\.js$/)) {
              fs.unlinkSync(path.join(compilation.outputOptions.path, key));
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you, apparently I'm not alone :) so I will wait for a patch.

Comment: Edited to add an example plugin to work around this problem.

Comment: Thanks for illustrating with a solution :)